# Need help positioning canvas element

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

As you can see here:

`[removed link]`

I have applied the following CSS to attempt to center my canvas element:

```
#particleCanvas{
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 98%;
}
```

for some reason, I the element is not being properly adjusted to the middle of the screen.  Any suggestions on what to adjust?

Comment: I would also suggest to have a "container element" with a set width for all your content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `display: block;` to your current rule so it reads:

```
#particleCanvas {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 98%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. As a side note, it's good practice to apply styles to classes rather than ID's. Consider changing the selector to `.particleCanvas` and adding this class to your canvas element. Do all your JS wizardry with the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you need to add a

```
display: block;
```

for the margin to work on this element